# Max of 2 columns with multiple group by lambda expression entity framework

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, lambda, entity-framework-6

I have the below query in lambda.

```
 var list = dbConnection.Form_Datas.Join(dbConnection.Forms, fd => fd.form_ID, f => f.form_ID,
            (fd, f) => new { form_data = fd, form = f })
            .Where(a => a.form_data.External_ID == personID)
            .Select(s => new FormDataDTO
            {
                FormID = s.form.form_ID,
                FormName = s.form.name,
                FormDataID = s.form_data.form_Data_ID,
                LastEdit = s.form_data.last_Edit,
                UserName = s.form_data.username
            }).OrderByDescending(o=>o.LastEdit).ToList();
```

I need to get the maximum value of LastEdit and FormDataID columns since formID and FormName is repetitive for one FormDataID. Also UserName should be shown from the max row values.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the `GroupBy`clause.

```
var list = dbConnection.Form_Datas
    .Join(dbConnection.Forms, fd => fd.form_ID, f => f.form_ID,
        (fd, f) => new { form_data = fd, form = f })
    .Where(a => a.form_data.External_ID == personID)
    .GroupBy(s => new 
    {
        FormID = s.form.form_ID,
        FormName = s.form.name,
        UserName = s.form_data.username 
    })
    .Select(s => new FormDataDTO
    {
        FormID = s.Key.form.form_ID,
        FormName = s.Key.form.name,
        FormDataID = s.Max(x => x.form_data.form_Data_ID),
        LastEdit = s.Max(x => x.form_data.last_Edit),
        UserName = s.Key.form_data.username
    }).OrderByDescending(o=>o.LastEdit).ToList();
```